# Python plotting missing data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

```
day = ([ 1 , 2 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9])
rain = ([0.6 , 0.8 , 1 , 6 , 6.5 ,7 , 4])
snow = ([ 1 , 2 , 0.5 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10])
```

if I want to plot day on x axis and rain and snow on y axis, and for example have a dotted line joining  for the days that are missing information how do I do this?

```
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(day,rain,  marker='o')
    plt.plot(day, snow, marker='o')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean *days that are missing information*? It seems like you have info for all your days here

Comment: If you want your markers connected by dotted line, just type `plt.plot(day,rain, ':o')`. The colon stands for dotted line

Comment: I mean for example for day 3  and 4 since the day does not exists, I want a dotted line joining 2 and 5

Comment: What have tried to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

day = ([ 1 , 2 , 3, 4, 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9])
rain = ([0.6 , 0.8 , np.nan, np.nan, 1 , 6 , 6.5 ,7 , 4])
snow = ([ 1 , 2 , np.nan, np.nan, 0.5 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10])

df = pd.DataFrame({'rain': rain, 'snow': snow}, index = day)
df.index.name = 'day'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(df['rain'].fillna(method='ffill'), ls = '--', lw = 1, label='_nolegend_')
ax.plot(df['rain'], color=line.get_color(), lw=1.5, marker = 'o')
line, = ax.plot(df['snow'].fillna(method='ffill'), ls = '--', lw = 1, label='_nolegend_')
ax.plot(df['snow'], color=line.get_color(), lw=1.5, marker = 'o')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('day')
plt.ylabel('mm')
plt.show()
```

[image]